# How to POST variables with a text link outside a form

Tags: php, html, forms, post

In my application I have a slide out menu coded as such...

```
echo "<nav>
      <h3>Menu</h3>";
      if ($_SESSION['true']==1) {
    if ($_GET['page']=="eventdetails") {
             echo "<a href='index.php?page=removeevent&EventID=".$_GET['EventID']
                   ."'>Remove Event</a>";
             echo "<a href='index.php?page=editevent&EventID="
                        .$_GET['EventID']."'>Edit Event</a>";
                    }   
                // Admin. tasks button
                echo "<a href='index.php?page=admintasks'>Admin. Tasks</a>";                                    
              }
echo "</nav>";
```

and I want to post fields in a form based on the click of the 'Edit Event' link; is there anyway to do this? I have used POST but only in the traditional method of having a submit button within the form tags but I don't know how I would do this when the button is outside the form tags.

Answer (score 2):

On element click event, you could do something like this and submit the form

```
$("#myAnchor").click(function(event)
{
    $('form#form_id').submit();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Include the preventDefault if you don't want the normal anchor behavior

Comment: So given a form_id of editForm I would place the following within my link?... onclick="$('form#editForm').submit();"

Comment: For neatness, should be.....if ($('form#form_id').onsubmit()) { $('form#form_id').submit(); } (and this pre-supposes you are you using jquery)

Answer (score 0):

First give your form a name:

```
<form name="mystuff">...
```

Then inside the link define an onclick handler that looks up the form in the DOM via the name and submits it:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.forms.mystuff.submit();">Edit event</a>
```